# Do i need to close pool connection for every api in nodejs+mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

My question is here i am creating pool for every API to get data from MySQL database, after query finish i am closing pool connection. Is there any performance issues if i do like this. what is best way to implement this.

Please excuse if i ask anything wrong, Thanks in advance.

```
firstapi: async (req, resp) => {
        let connection;
        try {
            connection = await mysql.createPool(db);
            let firstquery = "first query goes here";
            const [firstapidata] = await connection.execute(verlaufevortagquery);
            resp.json(firstapidata);
        } catch (error) {
            resp.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to execute query", Error: error });
        }
    },

    secondapi: async (req, resp) => {
        let connection;
        try {
            connection = await mysql.createPool(db);
            let secondquery = "second query goes here";
            const [secondata] = await connection.execute(verlaufevortagquery);
            resp.json(secondata);
        } catch (error) {
            resp.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to execute query", Error: error });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can keep the connection open, there is no reason to open it every time

```
let connection;
connection = await mysql.createPool(db);
firstapi: async (req, resp) => {

        try {
            use connection.execute here
        } catch (error) {
            resp.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to execute query", Error: error });
        }
    },

    secondapi: async (req, resp) => {
        try {
            use connection.execute here
        } catch (error) {
            resp.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to execute query", Error: error });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but what about connection close if i don't close connection is there any memory leaks happen.

Comment: If you don't close the connection, as long as you only open it once it will be destroyed when you exit the program @Urock

Comment: you mean there is no need to close the connection? please  elaborate bit more.

Comment: @Urock You can just close the connection when you press Ctrl+C or kill the app, no reason to create and destroy it many times